# Finding when a particular key was written into redis

Tags: redis

How can one find when a particular key was written to Redis i.e the create time.
Does redis maintain any meta information for this.

There is `PTTL` and `TTL` but this only works when one has set the time to live on keys.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to get this information unless you explicitly record it somewhere at write time. If this is something you need, store it in an auxiliary data structure that fits your use case.

Comment: We are doing like this, but the problem is you have to get the whole key back, de-serialize it and then get this information, this approach get more painful when you use redis hash (will you store with each data) also you can add more hashes.

Comment: @SantoshJoshi not sure I understand. If you're asking per key, you can just store all of this information in a single hash where the HASH keys are just equal to all of the keys in the db. Getting the time then requires no deserialization. You could make a simple custom command to return it with every GET using Lua. If you explain your use case more, I can give you a more explicit answer.

Comment: i might have complicated the question, the question is like,how can one find when a particular key( say Hash key) was written to redis. we are using redis hash to store our keys with [Super-Key {key:data , key:data}], with each key we store aux data containing the create time and other data. but we want to know when the redis hash (the Super-Key) was written. when we store this info with each key we need to get those key and then find the create time. but you might add more keys to your Super-key with different time. Also to get the create time from the inner key you need to deserialize